# creating an array, not working

Tags: linux, debian, array

I'm trying to create an array within a bash script. I am doing this:

```
#!/bin/bash
declare -a testArray1=('a/b/c.def -x -y -z','x/y/z.000 -a -b -c')

echo "testArray1[0] = ${testArray1[0]}"
echo "testArray1[1] = ${testArray1[1]}"
```

But it doesn't work. Everything is being added to a single `[0]` element for the array.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Use space instead of `,` as element separator.

Comment: simple when you know how. . . Cheers,

Answer (score 2):

Use this instead:

```
declare -a testArray1=('a/b/c.def -x -y -z' 'x/y/z.000 -a -b -c')
```

**BTW**: you can check the array structure with `declare -p`, see:

```
$ declare -a testArray1=('a/b/c.def -x -y -z','x/y/z.000 -a -b -c')
$ declare -p testArray1
declare -a testArray1='([0]="a/b/c.def -x -y -z,x/y/z.000 -a -b -c")'
$
$ declare -a testArray1=('a/b/c.def -x -y -z' 'x/y/z.000 -a -b -c')
$ declare -p testArray1
declare -a testArray1='([0]="a/b/c.def -x -y -z" [1]="x/y/z.000 -a -b -c")'
```